# Ubuntu Router Access Point

Tags: server, router, wireless-access-point

I made an Ubuntu Access Point. The AP is based on Ubuntu server 18.04. Initially it's working but after a while ( after reboot some times ) I can always connect with the AP but i have no access to Internet anymore and I can't use the SSH terminal ( DHCP works, seems to be a routing problem).
Pinging on the enp1s0 interface physically connected to the Home router works.
I used this procedure to make the AP works ( any help would be greatly appreciated ):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Packages installation:

```
sudo apt install ifupdown
sudo apt install bridge-utils
```

Network interface configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet manual

auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.2.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.2.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
bridge_ports enp2s0 wlp3s0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

Remove NETPLAN:

```
systemctl stop systemd-networkd.socket systemd-networkd networkd-dispatcher systemd-networkd-wait-online

systemctl disable systemd-networkd.socket systemd-networkd networkd-dispatcher systemd-networkd-wait-online

systemctl mask systemd-networkd.socket systemd-networkd networkd-dispatcher systemd-networkd-wait-online

apt-get --assume-yes purge nplan netplan.io
```

Enabling networking:

```
sudo systemctl unmask networking
sudo systemctl enable networking
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

DNS server configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
....
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
....

sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Enable IP Forwarding:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Reboot the server:

```
sudo reboot
```

Test DNS:

```
nslookup www.google.it
```

ACCESS POINT:

Packets installation:

```
sudo apt install wireless-tools
sudo apt install hostapd
```

Access point configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

interface=wlp3s0
driver=nl80211
bridge=br0
country_code=BO
ssid=APNAME
hw_mode=g
channel=10
logger_syslog=-1
wmm_enabled=1
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=APPASSWORD
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Access point test:

```
sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Enabling access point service:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/hostapd

DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

```
sudo systemctl unmask hostapd
sudo systemctl enable hostapd
sudo systemctl start hostapd
sudo systemctl status hostapd
```

DHCP server:

Package installation:

```
sudo apt install isc-dhcp-server
```

```
sudo nano /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

INTERFACESv4="br0"
```

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

option domain-name "domotica.org";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
ddns-update-style none;
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.2.4 192.168.2.254;
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
option domain-name "domotica.org";
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option routers 192.168.2.1;
option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
option ntp-servers 192.186.2.1;
option netbios-name-servers 192.168.2.1;
option netbios-node-type 2;
default-lease-time -1;
max-lease-time -1;
}
```

Enabling DHCP server:

```
sudo systemctl start isc-dhcp-server

sudo systemctl enable isc-dhcp-server
```

ROUTING:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE 

sudo apt install iptables-persistent
```

Sae IPV4 and IPV6

Restart the HUB

Comment: ❤️  By the way what is the question?

Comment: i can't figure out what is going wrong...

Comment: ufw firewall disabled, it's working….. and than not…

Comment: sudo iptables --list<br/>
<br/>
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)<br/>
target     prot opt source               destination<br/>
<br/>
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)<br/>
target     prot opt source               destination<br/>
<br/>
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)<br/>
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: Update: By following the procedure, remove netplan, do not enable networking, only reboot execute all the procedure steps without add the route. Connection with putty ( ssh ), if connected to the AP is possible, after reboot….. 1.2 or 3... connect to ssh isn't possible.

Comment: Problem solved. It works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer inside your question. Use the button below to write your own answer so that it can help others. After the 24 hour wait please accept your own answer as the correct one.